# Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain - org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, web.xml

I am new with spring. I am trying to use Spring Security to have authentication using MySQL, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
```

By judging from similar questions I think the security config file is not loaded.

my config file is in src/main/resources/spring-security.xml and I include it in awt.project.init.WebAppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("awt.project")
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-security.xml")
public class WebAppConfig {
 ....
}
```

Here is the web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<!-- Serves static resource content from .jar files such as spring-faces.jar -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map all /resources requests to the Resource Servlet for handling -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Java-based Spring container definition -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Location of Java @Configuration classes that configure the components that makeup this application -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    awt.project.init
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- Secures the application -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I tried to also include the spring-security.xml in contexConfiguration as `classpath:spring-security.xml` but still I get the same problem.

Here is the spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/sec/moderation.html" access="ROLE_MODERATOR" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <form-login login-page="/user-login.html"
        default-target-url="/success-login.html" authentication-failure-url="/error-login.html" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.html" />

</http> 

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: What does your spring-security.xml file look like?

Comment: I added the spring-security.xml

Comment: Seems like I had some dependency mismatches, after solving them the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but if you use `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` and specify only a package name in `contextConfigLocation`, Spring will scan that package only for classes with a stereotype annotation (`@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, etc), so your `WebAppConfig` is basically ignored. Try giving the fully qualified name of `WebAppConfig` as `contextConfigLocation`.

Comment: I tried awt.project.init.WebAppConfig in the contextConfigLocation but I still get the same erroe

Comment: One way to check to see that the spring-security.xml file is being loaded is to intentionally make it invalid XML which should produce an error stating the XML is invalid. Alternatively, you can enable debug logging to see if it is being loaded.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, it's not being loaded... how can I address it correctly? it's in the src/main/resources/spring-security.xml, is classpath:spring-security.xml correct?

Comment: That is the correct location. My guess is that WebAppConfig is not being found since would get an error if the resource for ImportResource was not found. Try enabling debug logging. If the logs do not help you, post them here. You can also try adding a debug point to the WebAppConfig to see if it is hit.

Comment: I found out another problem, I don't know if it is related, but maven MANIFEST.MF file is missing, and when I clean install the project the target folder only will have an empty META-INF folder!!!